# SaltStack : How I can copy file from minion to SaltStack File Server

Tags: salt-stack

I need to copy a file from a minion to the saltstack server file (salt://)

How can I achieve this ?

I tried a state like this but is not working.

```
copy:
  file.managed:
    - name: salt://a.txt
    - source: /tmp/a.txt
```

Hicham

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57971523/476716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cp.push`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.push):

```
copy:
  module.run:
    - name: cp.push
    - path: /tmp/a.txt
    - upload_path: /tmp
```

Note that as documented, for security purposes, you have to set `file_recv` to `True` in the master configuration file, and restart the master, in order to enable this feature, and even then the minion is only allowed to upload the file to the minion's cache directory (`/var/cache/salt/master/minions/minion-id/files`). Specifying `upload_path` would upload the file to a sub-directory inside the cache directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Do you know if this directory is accessible for other minions ?

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately again for security purposes each minion has its own cache directory as indicated by the `minion-id` part of the cache directory path name.

Comment: @hbellahc it is if you configure `minionfs`