# Is there any salt function or state to copy folder/files from minion to minon or minion to master?

Tags: salt-stack

Is there any salt function or state to copy folder/files from minion to minon or minion to master

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you may also be able to push files from minion to master using the [cp.push](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.push) or [cp.push_dir](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.push_dir)

But you will have to activate the file_recv option on your master side.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is [SCP module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.scp_mod.html). it does not copy file or directories to master, but the workaround is to install a minion on master.

some notes: be sure you installed salt with python3. and you should install scp with pip (also pip3!, use bin_env in pip.install for this)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for this:

- The [Salt Mine](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/mine/) for small data packets (e.g. public keys)
- Using [`minionfs`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/tutorials/minionfs.html) for larger files and directories (e.g. build server output)
- An [`rsync.synchronized`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.rsync.html) state
- Any other method of copying files, which you can then configure with salt ([`scp`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.scp_mod.html), [`mount`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.mount.html#module-salt.states.mount), [`ftp`, etc.](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed))

Some methods make the files accessible to all minions, so you may need to consider that, and other security needs.